# Use an iOS framework that has dependency on some pods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have created a framework project in Xcode -that has dependency on some pods- to be able to use in different Xcode projects.
How can Xcode be informed to get that framework the dependency it needs?

Comment: Please read the instructions on https://cocoapods.org/ on how to create a pod

Comment: Please add more information about dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the dependencies on frameworks [or on other pods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency) in the podspec file. This file will explain to cocoapods how to correctly bind the pod in your XCode project.

You have an example at the end of the second sample [in this page](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#specification).